# Google page rank checking Asp.Net script

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, rank

I am in search of some `ASP.NET` script by which I can get the Google PageRank of any URL that I provide to it, can anyone guide me in this perspective?

Comment: Ummmm, did you try Google? I mean the search engine...